# How to disable control+A shortcut for QTableView and prevent select all option?

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling

I want to prevent `control+A` shortcut from selecting all the files in `QTableView`, I want to make it as such that it can only select with mouse but not with a keyboard shortcut. Right now my `eventFilter` code is as below. Could you please suggest me a way to do that?

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent *ev)
{
    if(ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        if(obj == ui->listOfImages->viewport())
        {
            QMouseEvent * mouseEv = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(ev);
            if((mouseEv->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && (QApplication::keyboardModifiers().testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier) == true))
            {
                controlButtonCounter++;
                fetch = true;
                return QObject::eventFilter(obj,ev);
            }
            else if((mouseEv->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && (QApplication::keyboardModifiers().testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier) == false))
            {
                if(selectedImages.size()>0)
                {
                    ui->listOfImages->clearSelection();
                    selectedImages.clear();
                    selectedList.clear();
                    ui->selectedFiles->clear();
                    ui->selectedFiles->show();
                }
                fetch = false;
                controlButtonCounter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj,ev);
}
```

Comment: Does setting the `selectionMode` to `QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection` work, even by allowing the CTRL+A combination? Basically, it should prevent the selection of multiple rows.

Comment: You need to check whether the key event occurred with `Ctrl+A` key combination and return true, i.e. filter the event.

Comment: Sorry for naivety, but how do I check if Ctrl+A is pressed? I can't see any method to do that. @vahancho

Answer (score 0):

I would try to extend your event filter's code with the following block:

```
[..]
if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress && obj == ui->listOfImages->viewport()) { 
    QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);

    int key = keyEvent->key();
    Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifiers = keyEvent->modifiers();
    if(modifiers & Qt::ShiftModifier) 
        key += Qt::SHIFT; 
    if(modifiers & Qt::ControlModifier) 
        key += Qt::CTRL; 
    if(modifiers & Qt::AltModifier) 
        key += Qt::ALT; 
    if(modifiers & Qt::MetaModifier) 
        key += Qt::META; 

    if (QKeySequence(key) == QKeySequence(QKeySequence::SelectAll)) {
        // Filter the event.
        return true;
    }
}
[..]
```

This code is supposed to return true (filter the event) if standard "select all" key combination pressed. It is usually Ctrl+A keys.